# Problemas para activar la excepción

Tags: python-3.x

Estoy haciendo unos ejemplos de repaso para try y except pero me aparece "none" cuando realizo el error.

```
nombre = input("¿Cual es tu nombre?: ")


def control(param):
    try:
        if len(param) > 1:
            nombre_retornado = "El nombre es " + param

            return nombre_retornado

    except NameError:
        return "Ha ocurrido un error, ingrese bien el nombre"


print(control(nombre))
```

Cuando muevo el return nombre_retornado al nivel del if funciona, pero Pycharm detecta un error de identación, que es lo que estoy haciendo mal? y como puedo mejorar mi codigo?

Comment: Revisa que no tengas una mezcla de TAB y espacios para la identación, puedes usar cualquiera de los dos, pero nunca juntos

Comment: también podrías intentar poner el return en un else después del except